# How to detect size grip double-click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, window-resize

I'm looking for a way to detect double-click on a window size grip, but there doesn't seem to be even a single click event for the size grip, or any event related to it at all. Guessing the size of grip area and whether the user is truly clicking the desired area is an unnecessarily difficult job. But maybe there are some other ways to detect if the cursor is 
on a form's size grip, besides default winform properties?

Is there an easy way to know when user is double-clicking a form's size grip?

Comment: Size grip is not in the client area and windows form does not provide event for mouse input except control button. so, you cannot get any event for form's grip. Yes you can do this using some windows API by mouse hook. but, you have to identity is your mouse clicked on grip or not. because Mouse Hook will perform for whole screen not for particular object.

Comment: Well, Windows somehow knows when you click and drag that grip, so there's gotta be some way.

Comment: Windows also provides context menu when you right click on title bar. can access it? might have some way to get that. but, without windows api i think it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Set up a way to receive a mouse double-click event on the non-client area of the form.
2. Define a hitbox within which you care to react to that event.
3. React to the event when it's in your hitbox.

Override the `WndProc` form method to achieve this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const Int32 WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0xA3;
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            //This is a 16x16 region...define the bounds you want...
            Rectangle hitbox = new Rectangle(this.Right - 16, this.Bottom - 16, 16, 16);
            Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
            if (hitbox.Contains(pos))
                MessageBox.Show("got it");  //react however you like
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```